# System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser() problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my controller action I am trying to do the following:

```
var roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(userFromDb.UserName).ToList();
userViewModel.UserRoles = roles;
```

What happened after is that I got this error: "The Role Manager feature has not been enabled."

So I added the following in my webconfig file:

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true"/>
</system.web>
```

Now When I start my app and the layout page is loading it reaches to the following line:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrator") == true)
```

and gives me this error: "Unable to connect to SQL Server database"

What can I do to be able to use Roles.GetRolesForUser()?
Or is there anything else I can use to get the roles of a user?

Comment: where's your connection string?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after a while I found another way to do it:

```
//it gives you a List<string> whit the name of the roles
var roles = UserManager.GetRoles(userGuid);
```

You will have to add this to your controller if you don't have it already:

```
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```